# I want to use MRTK(Mixed Reality Tool Kit) gesture with script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I want to control MRTK input actions(select, scroll, hold, etc.) with script.

I'm trying to make custom controller, using EMG sensor.

When I received data from sensor, I need to control MRTK input actions depending on the data.

I tried to use some profiles (DefaultMixedRealityInputActionsProfile, MixedRealityInputSystemProfile ...) but they only provided data, not writable.

I also tried to use ViGEm, virtual game controller, but it was only available in unity test, not available at hololens because I don't know how to connect ViGEm and Hololens with wireless.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to create a custom input system data provider based on your EMG sensor. For a step-by-step guide to getting started please refer to this link: [Create data provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/input/create-data-provider?view=mrtkunity-2021-01). And then, you can raise HoloLens gesture events corresponding to controller state changes by invoking the [RaiseGestureStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.mixedrealityinputsystem.raisegesturestarted?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.6.0) method in your custom data provider class. For example, have a look at [WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/main/Assets/MRTK/Providers/WindowsMixedReality/XRSDK/WindowsMixedRealityDeviceManager.cs) which implements raising gesture input events and wraps the Unity [XR.WSA.Input.GestureRecognizer](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.Input.GestureRecognizer.html) to consume Unity's gesture events from HoloLens devices.